# To search a grid for a value in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect, extjs5

var record = store.findRecord('InterviewerID', id);

This line searches for the record visible on the grid.
If the record is present in the next page(Pagination) then it does not search.
Could you please provide a way to search the whole store?

Comment: tell me what is your spesific problem. please add the necessery code you have.

Comment: I want to clone a store in extjs5.

Comment: A "clone" ? You mean, you want to use the store multiple times or just duplicate the store ? Or anything else ?

Comment: And, what is your backend for the extjs you used ? a PHP ? Or ASP ? Or anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

The findBy approach still would not work.

Your store will only contain a single page of data returned from the server. To search across pages you would need to search server side and determine which page of data it exists on. Once you know which page of data the searched term exists on, you could load that page of data into your store.

Comment: Thanks I am using **client side pagination** .But still it searches for only in the page which is visible.

Comment: Can you post some extra code, so maybe your store config and how you are handling the pagination side of things?